# Want to parse arabic and english from an image

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, tesseract.js

I want to parse text from an image, the image conatins arabic and english both. I am using tesseract.js to parse the text from the image but keep getting an error "langsArr.map is not a function"

Below is the code

```
const { createWorker } = require("tesseract.js");

async function recognizeImage() {
const worker = createWorker({
workerPath:
"https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js@5.0.3/dist/worker.min.js",
langPath: "./tessdata",
corePath: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/tesseract.js-core@5.0.0",
});

await worker.load();
// Replace 'eng+ara' with the specific languages you want to recognize
await worker.loadLanguage("eng", "ara");
await worker.initialize(\["eng", "ara"\]);

const {
    data: { text },
} = await worker.recognize("./receipt images/loremArabic.png");
    console.log("Recognized text:", text);

await worker.terminate();
}

recognizeImage().catch((err) =\> console.error(err.message));
```

Libraries versions I am using are
"tesseract.js": "^5.0.3",
"tesseract.js-core": "^5.0.0",

I am expecting to get the text from the image
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F5A9I.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pM5Un.jpg)